# c# Can't get Host name

Tags: c#, dns, hostname

Hello i use this code to get host name from all devices connected to the same network

```
            string hostname = string.Empty;
            string mac = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse(ip));

                if (ipEntry != null) hostname = ipEntry.HostName;
            }catch(SocketException se)
            {
                hostname = "Unknown Host name !";
            }
```

I use a loop to get the IP from x.x.x.2 to x.x.x.254
i get the host name from a computer's IP 
but mobile phones such as android or IPhone or WindowsPhone
it throws a SocketException Why is That happening ?
because when i log into the router page and look for Devices
I realise that all the devices that i can't get their names are mobile phones
and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Post the stack trace please

Comment: sorry! how can I get that ?

Comment: Debug/Windows/Call Stack, or in your catch block print se.ToString() and paste the result here

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Hôte inconnu
   à System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6)
   à System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress address)
   à Test.GetDev.PingCompleted(Object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e) dans c:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\GetDev.cs:ligne 367

if youdon't understand french that means Unknown Host

Comment: If a hostname is not registered in the DNS, GetHostEntry can't give you the hostname.

Comment: I'm french. Are you sure that your devices are configured to use IPV4 and not IPV6?

Comment: @Wimmel is there any other way to get it because I can see host names in the router config page how can the router know their names !

Comment: @LoveMetal I'm not sure ! is IPv6 the cause of the exception ?

Comment: @Th3Wolf the router probably gets it from a DHCP request.

Comment: @Wimmel Ok I'll try to find another way. Thank you for your help !